# C# UWP XAML Check If Exists in XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Im working on building different layouts for my app. If the app runs in landscape I want to be able to show a map on one side on the screen, but not show a map if in portrait. I'm using VisualStateManager to help me do this.

I need to run some code in c# on the map control I have named "MyMap" but how can I make that bit of the code run only when the map is present - in other words is there a way I can check if it exists in the XAML?

Without the map any code referring to MyMap of course throws an error - is this the best way of going about this or am I missing a better way?

**EDIT**

I'm using an approach similar to the below to work out what template should be used depending on the MinWindowWidth. So MyMap will only exist in the LargeTemplate etc

```
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="SmallTemplate">
        <Grid>
            <Border Background="LightGray" Height="100" Width="100">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" 
                          FontSize="48" Foreground="Green" />
            </Border>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="LargeTemplate">
        <Grid>
            <Border Background="LightGray" Height="200" Width="200">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" 
                          FontSize="48" Foreground="Green" />
            </Border>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualState x:Name="Small">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="MyGridView.ItemTemplate" Value="{StaticResource SmallTemplate}" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="Large">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="720" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="MyGridView.ItemTemplate" Value="{StaticResource LargeTemplate}" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups> 
    <GridView Name="MyGridView"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: can you post some code to show how you used visualstatemanager to accomplish this? Are you simply hiding it or are you destroying/creating the map object?

Comment: Just updated my post to show a technique I'm trying to adapt.

Comment: Did you try this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.visualtreehelper  Requires looping, through objects though  theres an example here http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/09/how-to-access-named-control-inside-xaml.html

Comment: So if it's similar to the example you have here, what's the property you're targeting with the Setter? Is it just `Visibility` for example? If that's the case just watch the property change on the property for Collapsed vs Visible right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an x:Name to your VisualStateGroup eg. *AdaptiveVisualStateGroup*, after that you can check for the CurrentState in your code like this:
*AdaptiveVisualStateGroup.CurrentState*

If the CurrentState equals *Large* or whatever the name is your VisualState where you have your map, you can run the code that references *MyMap*, otherwise you just skip it

Comment: Good suggestion but visual studio is throwing errors about "The name 'MyMap' does not exist in the current context" once I move the map control into the data template within Page.Resources